# Node / Express race condition on DB operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mutex

I have an express route that needs to retrieve a row from a db, check if a field has a value set and if not set it. The row data then gets sent back to the client.

I know that node runs on a single thread but I/O operations do actually run asynchronously so I think I may have a problem if whilst the first client is waiting to write to db, a second client comes and reads a null value and performs the write a second time.

I can't have this happen as the value written is a shared value that there can only be one of.

Am I correct that this could happen and if so what is a recommended way to handle this?

Thanks.

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();

router.post('/getRoomStateByRoomUrl', async (req, res, next) => {
    const roomUrl = req.body.room_url;
    try {
        //READ FROM DB
        const roomState = await RoomStateModel.getRoomStateByRoomUrl(roomUrl);

        if(!roomState.tokboxSessionID) {
            const newSessionID = await TokboxService.createSession();
            
            //WRITE TO DB
            await RoomStateModel.setTokboxSessionID(newSessionID);
            
            roomState.tokboxSessionID = newSessionID;
        }
        res.status(200).json(roomState);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: You are correct that this could be a race condition. Anywhere you get a value from the database, modify it and write it back is a potential race condition.  This is why databases contain atomic operations such as increment or upsert or find and modify. I don't know your database (you don't say which one it is), but usually the best solution is to use the atomic operations your database provides for modifying data. So, probably you need to explore modify `roomState` using an atomic operation. Some databases expose temporary locks that can also be used, but using atomic operations is preferable.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using MySQL. I will look into it.

Comment: OK, SQL.  That gives you programming opportunities within the SQL to avoid race conditions where you can put some logic within the SQL instead of in your Javascript.  But, atomic database update operations are always the place to start.